Parte superior estatica en editor de codigo de Visual Studio Code
Buen dia, no se que hice en visual studio code, pero en mi codigo html cada vez que bajo, en la parte superior de mi editor de codigo se me queda estatico esa seccion que señale en el recuadro rojo, desinstale varias extensiones que tenia pensando que talvez era eso pero sigue igual y es algo incomodo para mi.


Ni siquiera te has molestado en leer el changelog de las nuevas funcionalidades de VSC, eh??? Porque ahí literalmente explican ese funcionamiento... Es una nueva funcionalidad que permite siempre tener visible la estructura dentro de la que te encuentras. Útil a veces, supongo. Pero vamos... investigar es necesario antes de preguntar.

@Benito, dado que StackOverflow es un recurso tan útil para la investigación de otras personas, considero valioso tener esta pregunta y una respuesta adecuada a ella. Ya que sabes del tema, ¿la escribirías?

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Para realizar lo que comentas puedes hacer de las siguientes formas:

El elemento que haces mencion es llamado 'stickyScroll' por lo tanto...

Forma 1:

Da click derecho al 'stickyScroll' y te desplegara 2 opciones, desactiva la que está activa. (por lo regular está activa 1 opción que es la de el 'stickyScroll')

Forma 2:

Entra al settings.json de tu Visual Studio.


Puedes acceder con la combinación de teclas 'Ctrl + Shift + P' y buscar por 'settings.json' o 'Preferencias: Abrir configuración de usuario (JSON)'


Ya que tengas abierto el settings.json añade la siguiente línea que ocultará el 'stickyScroll':

"editor.stickyScroll.enabled": false
